# Looking for an alternative to messy SQL ISNULL/NULLIF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query running on SQL Server 2012 that needs to compare a bit value and return a string if that value is 1 and an empty string if it is zero.

Originally I had it as a CASE statement like this:

```
CASE WHEN myBit = 0 THEN 
 -- do other comparisons etc to build up the return string.
 +'myString' 
ELSE 
-- do other comparisons etc to build up the return string.
'' END
```

The problem is that all of the code in 'do other' section is the same. All I want to do is append a string to the returned value if the bit is zero and nothing if it is 1.

So I refactored it to only have the common code once and then append to the string at the end like this:

```
-- do other comparisons etc to build up the return string. +
ISNULL(NULLIF(Cast(ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(myBit, 0) AS NVARCHAR), 'myString') AS varchar),'0'),'')
```

However the above seems very messy not least because of the CAST statements required.

I'm looking for a clean and neat way of doing this but have run out of ideas - anyone have a better way of achieving this?  Thanks.

Comment: Remember, CASE is a Function/Expression, *not* a Clause, so you can use it in the same places that you use ISNULL, NULLIF or any other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `IIF` and `CONCAT` as you are on SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT CONCAT('Start',
              IIF(@mybit=0,'myString',''),
              'End')
```

`IIF` is a bit more concise than `CASE`. `CONCAT` might be beneficial in that it casts non string types to strings automatically and concatenating `NULL` is treated the same as concatenating an empty string.

Comment: I didn't know about these functions they will be really useful to me, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just add your CASE statement inline. Don't forget to return an empty string when mybit=1, or the whole thing will return NULL.

```
Select 
-- do other comparisons etc to build up the return string.
 + Case When @mybit=0 Then mystring else '' End
```

Comment: I had tried putting the CASE inline but I ended up with an empty value. I thought it just wouldn't work like that but at least I now know it must have been something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use a *simple* `case` here as;

```
Select 'Your other string ' +  
       Case mybit When 0 then 'mystring' else '' End As Results

--Results will be like
mybit    Results
0        'Your other string mystring'
1        'Your other string '
```

***OR*** if you want nothing (null) to return if `mybit <> 0` then use a simple case *without else* part as;

```
Select 'Your other string ' +  Case mybit When 0 then 'mystring' End As Results

--Results will be like
mybit    Results
0        'Your other string mystring'
1        null
```

[**SQL-SERVER-DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b61d2/2) for both cases

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. I had tried putting the case inline but had problems. At least now I know it must have been something else giving me trouble and not the inline case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the common code into a subquery?  It would resemble this:

```
select case when myBit = 0 then value else value + 'what you append' end returnvalue
from
(subquery with common code) abc
```

Or maybe a function

```
select case when myBit = 0 then yourfunction() 
else yourfunction + 'what you append' end returnvalue
```